# How to make a public google colab notebook for every individual users?

Tags: garbage-collection, public, collaboration, rnotebook

I would like to create a public Google Colab notebook that people can use and access that document, but I am not sure how to create a notebook that is Publically available on google collab.

Can Anyone here help me to make the Public Google collab Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option that you make your google colab public independently. However, you can share your notebook with anybody by sharing the shareable link.

Apart from that if you want to showcase your project(i.e NOTEBOOK, requirement.txt, dataset, etc) then upload it on GitHub and make it public.

For more information you can check [enter link description here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can send it to a site that displays user-uploaded Colabs, like https://colabrating.com/